# AWS Quicksight Scatter Plot Using Timestamps

Tags: scatter-plot, amazon-quicksight

Does anyone know how I can plot Datetime timestamps on the Y axis of a scatter plot? I want to have a visual of when records are spaced throughout the day. So I am looking to put Users on the X and timestamps on the Y. However, Quicksight will not allow me to add the Datetime field on the visual, as it states it must be a numeric measure. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a member of QuickSight team. Current version of QuickSight only supports numeric fields on both axis of the scatter plot. Let me open a bug for it and investigate what it would take to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Tatyana, I look forward to hearing further on this.

Comment: Same here, timestamp on X axis would be great, for now the plotting function is useless without this... atm it's back to Google spreadshit